# Why is Future not returned from actor to ScalaTest's whenReady?

Tags: scala, akka

I am having an issue with a `Future` that is not returned from an actor in a ScalaTest case using `whenReady`.

Here is the test case

```scala
"A PolicyHolderDAO Actor" must { 
  "return a failure if given a policy holder to update without an id" in { 
    val updatePolicyHolderFailureAny : Future[Any] = policyHolderDAOActor ? PoliHolderDAO.Update(Future(policyHolder))
    val updatePolicyHolderFailure : Future[PolicyHolderDAO.Failure] = updatePolicyHolderFailureAny.mapTo[PolicyHolderDAO.Failure]
    whenReady(updatePolicyHolderFailure, timeout(5 seconds), interval(5 millis)) { failure => 
      failure.error.getMessage must be ("When updating a policy holder, we must have an id")
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the `receive` method of the actor:

```
override def receive = {
  case PolicyHolderDAO.Update(policyHolder) => 
    val s = sender
    policyHolder map { p =>
      p match {
        case _ if p.id.isDefined => s ! update(policyHolder)
        case _  => println("HERE"); s ! PolicyHolderDAO.Failure(throw new IllegalArgumentException("When updating a policy holder, we must have an id"), None)
      }
    }
}
```

The `Update` case class is as follows

```
case class Update(policyHolder : Future[PolicyHolder]
```

What I am trying to do is to check to see if the policy holder has an `id`. If it has an `id`, pass it on to the `update` method, if it does not have an `id`, return a failure. The happy path works fine, and the sad path seems to work fine as well, by that I mean `println("HERE")` is executed. However my test case seems to not receive a reply from the actor in the sad path scenario.

Here is the error message

```
[info] A PolicyHolderDAO Actor
HERE
[info] - must return a failure if given a policy holder to update without an id *** FAILED ***
[info]   A timeout occurred waiting for a future to complete. Queried 980 times, sleeping 5000000 nanoseconds between each query. (PolicyHolderDAOSystemTest.scala:103)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PolicyHolderDAO.Failure(throw new IllegalArgumentException("When updating a policy holder, we must have an id"), None)
```

Means that you will throw an IllegalArgumentException, so no message gets constructed and the error will be sent to the actor supervisor.

What you meant is to create the exception and return it inside a message, right?

```
PolicyHolderDAO.Failure(new IllegalArgumentException("When updating a policy holder, we must have an id"), None)
```